# AzureDevOps dashboard configuration: change milliseconds to minutes in y axis

Tags: dashboard

I added Test Results Trend widget to AzureDevOps dashboard but it is displaying Duration in milliseconds and not in minutes as I would like it to be. There seems to be no way of changing that. The strange thing is that other Test Results Trend widgets display results in minutes, yet others - in seconds. Is it a bug or it is configurable somewhere (it seems impossible to find where)?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from developercommunity.visualstudio.com: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/554747/azure-devops-5.html
Basically it says currently it is impossible to configure duration units.